# setxkbmap -layout us,pt doesn't work

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, i3

I'm using i3 and imported some keybinds from another user that has the US keyboard.
From the i3 forums, the easiest way to do this would be to do:

```
setxkbmap -layout us,pt .....
```

This solution seems to work fine with other keymaps (ca,fr, etc)
but when it comes to PT, it doesn't work no matter what I do.

I have a little script that is executed when i3 starts.
This script is located on `.config/i3/config` with `exec --no-startup-id keybindremap`

The script in question is as it follows:

```
xset r rate 300 50
setxkbmap -model acer_laptop -layout pt -variant ,, -option caps:super
killall xcape 2>/dev/null ; xcape -e 'Super_L=Escape'
xmodmap -e 'keycode 135 = Super_R'
```

My problem is when I do:

```
setxkbmap -model acer_laptop -layout us,pt -variant ,, -option caps:super
```

the keyboard STAYS on the `us` setting.

Comment: `setxkbmap -model acer_laptop -layout us,pt`. If you put `us` first, this mapping will have precedence over the `pt`. What about if you use only `-layout pt` or `-layout pt,us` ?